# Compiling Haskell to JavaScript using GHCJS and Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghcjs

How can Haskell be compiled to Javascript using GHCJS and Haskell Stack?

I have the current version of Haksell Stack `1.5.1`.

I can initialize a GHCJS project with this command:  `stack new ghcjsSetup ghcjs`

Once in the project directory I try following the [Stack documentation for GHCJS](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/ghcjs/#ghcjs).

I create a `stack.yaml` file and edit it to match the example from the documentation so that is looks like this.

```
resolver: lts-7.19
compiler: ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1
compiler-check: match-exact

setup-info:
  ghcjs:
    source:
      ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1:
        url: http://ghcjs.tolysz.org/ghc-8.0-2017-02-05-lts-7.19-9007019.tar.gz
        sha1: d2cfc25f9cda32a25a87d9af68891b2186ee52f9
```

Following the documentation further I try to install and boot GHCJS with this command:

`stack setup`

This command produces an output which ends with an error.

```
Preparing to install GHCJS to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Preparing to download ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1 ...
Already downloaded.
Unpacking GHCJS into /home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/ ...
Setting up GHCJS build environment
Installing GHCJS (this will take a long time) ...
ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019: configure (lib + exe)
Package ghcjs uses a custom Cabal build, but does not use a custom-setup stanza
Using the explicit setup deps approach based on configuration
Strongly recommend fixing the package's cabal file
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/Setup.hs, /home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/setup/Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /home/u/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/setup/StackSetupShim.o )
Linking /home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/setup/setup ...
Configuring ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019...
ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019...

/home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/src/Compiler/JMacro/Base.hs:1:55: warning:
    -XOverlappingInstances is deprecated: instead use per-instance pragmas OVERLAPPING/OVERLAPPABLE/OVERLAPS

/home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/src/Compiler/JMacro/QQ.hs:1:55: warning:
    -XOverlappingInstances is deprecated: instead use per-instance pragmas OVERLAPPING/OVERLAPPABLE/OVERLAPS
[ 1 of 50] Compiling GHCJS.Prim.TH.Serialized ( lib/ghcjs-prim/GHCJS/Prim/TH/Serialized.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/GHCJS/Prim/TH/Serialized.o )
```

Because it is too long to post here I have excluded the middle of the output.  Which includes lots of warning messages.

```
[49 of 50] Compiling Compiler.Program ( src/Compiler/Program.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/Compiler/Program.o )
[50 of 50] Compiling GHCJS            ( src/GHCJS.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/GHCJS.o )
Preprocessing executable 'ghcjs' for ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src-bin/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/ghcjs/ghcjs-tmp/Main.o )
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/ghcjs/ghcjs ...
Preprocessing executable 'ghcjs-boot' for ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src-bin/Boot.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/ghcjs-boot/ghcjs-boot-tmp/Main.o )

/home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/src-bin/Boot.hs:690:1: warning: [-Wtabs]
    Tab character found here, and in three further locations.
    Please use spaces instead.
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/ghcjs-boot/ghcjs-boot ...
Preprocessing executable 'ghcjs-pkg' for ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src-bin/Pkg.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/ghcjs-pkg/ghcjs-pkg-tmp/Main.o )
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/ghcjs-pkg/ghcjs-pkg ...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building package ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019 using:
      /home/u/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1/src/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build lib:ghcjs exe:ghcjs exe:ghcjs-boot exe:ghcjs-pkg exe:ghcjs-run exe:haddock-ghcjs exe:hsc2hs-ghcjs --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: The package which the linker cannot find is [this one](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libtinfo-dev). Do you have it installed?

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for pointing out the Debian package `libtinfo-dev`.  When I do `stack setup` after installing that package it gets by that error.  Now I get "fatal: program node is required but could not be found at node".  I will install node and try again.

Comment: I have installed nodejs using the Debian package manager but when I try `stack setup` I am still getting the same error message.  So I am not sure what it is referring to when it says node.

Comment: Different distros call the executable either node or nodejs, IIRC. You may need to create a symlink for the other name

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman yes you are right.  In Debian there is another package that symlinks nodejs to node called `nodejs-legacy`.  After installing that I am able to do finish `stack setup` and also `stack build`.  And the alert saying "hello from GHCJS!" pops up when I open the index.html in the executables directory.  So it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

"`Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/ghcjs-pkg/ghcjs-pkg ...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo`"

You are missing the `libtinfo` library which is part of ncurses. Depending on your environment try something like:

`sudo apt-get install libtinfo-dev`

---

As an aside, getting all the pieces that `ghcjs` needs to build successfully is tricky and not well documented as of September 2018.  One might hope that as the project matures it will get easier to install, and that a binary package will be produced. Know that you are not the only person who has these issues. It takes some patience and trial-and-error to get `ghcjs` working right now.

Others have had success using [nix](https://nixos.org/nix/), [I did not](https://xkcd.com/927/).